# how to initiate a foreign key when you add a new record?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6

I have a little problem. I want to test a connection of two tables.

```
public class Patient:Person
{
    //inheritance ID
    public string insuranceNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual PatientCard patientCard {get; set;}

}

public class PatientCard
    {

        public PatientCard()
        {
            this.patient = new HashSet<Patient>();
            this.visit = new HashSet<Visit>();
        }

        public long id { get; set; }
        public string bloodType { get; set; }
        public string creationDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Patient> patient { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Visit> visit { get; set; }
    }
```

how to initiate a foreign key when you add a new record?
My attempt looks like this ...

```
                var patient = new Patient { 
                    ID=1, name = "Alicja", lastname = "Nowacka", 
                    pesel = "89192232", address = "Szczecin", 
                    phoneNumber = "11233332", insuranceNumber = "3211233123" 
                };
                db.Persons.Add(patient);
                db.SaveChanges();


                var patientCard = new PatientCard { 
                    bloodType = "A", creationDate = "2014-06-16", 
                    patient= //**a reference to the key**
                };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is your foreign key reference to? ID of Patient? 
If ID is Identity you just need to get `patient.Id` after `db.SaveChanges();`

Comment: Yes, my foreign key is ID, I tried to directly initiate patient=1, but  I get an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MySQLTest.Entity.Patient>"

Comment: You should try this way: patientCard.patient.add(patient)